# How to check for address type and NULL with a Smarty token after Smarty changes in 5.63?

Tags: civimail, smarty

I am getting two issues after upgrade from 5.58 to 5.63 related to Smarty in message templates.

In one case, the location_type_id no longer seems to valid.

```
{capture assign=type}{contact.address_primary.location_type_id:label}{/capture}   
{if $type == Work}{$employer}{/if}
```

> syntax error: (secure mode) 'Work' not allowed in if statement
> (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1398)

Perplexingly in the other, != NULL does not see to be a valid operator value combination.

```
{capture assign=donor_port}{contact.custom_65}{/capture}
{if $donor_port != NULL}
Donor Portfolio: {$donor_port}
{/if}
```

> syntax error: (secure mode) 'NULL' not allowed in if statement (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1398)

Any ideas what the replacements for these are, is there **new syntax documentation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure these changes would be considered a "new" syntax rather than a stricter enforcement of existing syntax, causing heretofore-unnoticed syntax errors to rear their heads.

For the first, the string needs to be quoted. Unquoted strings throw a notice at least, or I think an error in later versions of PHP. So it should be:

```
{if $type == 'Work'}{$employer}{/if}
```

For the second, `{capture}` always captures a string (whatever is inside the `{capture}{/capture}`) so will never be anything other than a string. You could change your conditional to `{if $donor_port != ''}`, or simplify it further to `{if $donor_port}`.

Comment: Thank you @Coleman. Quotes fixed it

Comment: No problem, although looking at it again, the only thing inside your `{capture}` is another token, so why not use that token directly? I don't think capturing it serves any purpose.